# Symfony Xdebug PhpStorm doesn’t work after setup

Tags: php, xdebug

I followed this [Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.2/configuring-xdebug.html?utm_source=product&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=PS&utm_content=2021.2) to setup Xdebug in PhpStorm. But it doesn’t work.

The Xdebug section of my php.ini looks like this:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.client_port=9000
```

If I run the `php -v` it shows me that Xdebug isn't installed. I don't understand why...

Comment: Which version of XDebug do you use? How is this related to Symfony itself?

Comment: This Problem is not related to Symfony. Its an "pure" PHP-Configuration Problem.

Comment: If I see it wide version 2.6

Comment: 1) *"If I run the `php -v` and it shows me that XDbug isn't installed."* You must be editing the wrong php.ini then. Run `php --ini` to see what config files that particular PHP is using. **P.S.** Please note that on Mac and Linux it's very common to have separate php.ini for CLI (terminal) and web server. So you have to check your config in the same environment (CLI or a web page) where you trying to debug.

Comment: 2) BTW: You most likely have Xdebug v3 by now .. but in your config you are trying to mix Xdebug v2 and v3 params (and params from v2 do nothing on v3). See this doc for  that: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone it helps a lot. I fixed the problem I use the https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fix the Problem with this information from @LazyOne

1. "If I run the php -v and it shows me that XDbug isn't installed." You must be editing the wrong php.ini then. Run php --ini to see what config files that particular PHP is using. P.S. Please note that on Mac and Linux it's very common to have separate php.ini for CLI (terminal) and web server. So you have to check your config in the same environment (CLI or a web page) where you trying to debug.

and this link from him xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide. This helps to find the right XDebug version.

Thanks for the Help @LazyOne